# GAE App Engine Websocket clients are disconnected after 1 hour

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, websocket

I have a simple Websocket server deployed to AppEngine, after exactly 1 hour clients are disconnected with error code 1006, I believe this is happening because of the nginx load balancer, I have tried changing nginx-app.conf, but it didn't help

```
  proxy_send_timeout 7d;
  proxy_read_timeout 7d;
```

My server is sending ping / pong frames every 10 seconds, so inactivity is out of the question.

The official GAE documentation states this:

"WebSockets are always available to your application without any additional setup. Once a WebSockets connection is established, it will time out after one hour."

But there is no information about how to circumvent this.

How can I ensure that my socket stay alive for an unlimited amount of time?

Comment: Could you please provide more details and possibly some sample code ?
Also have you seen this Medium article ? https://medium.com/google-cloud/highly-available-websockets-on-google-cloud-c74b35ee20bc

It seems to be close to what I understand is what you want.

Comment: This is easily reproduced with a basic websocket server, I solved this by moving to Compute Engine, this lets me configure the LB myself, and it costs twice as little :)